# Extract lines matching specific pattern + additional manipulation

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Given a list of directories and/or file paths, I want to extract the paths of the directories containing files with names matching a given pattern, e.g. files having a `.txt` extension.

Sample input file:

```
/a/b/c/d.txt
/a/b/c/d/e.txt
f
g
h/i
/a/b/c.txt
```

Expected output:

```
/a/b/c/
/a/b/c/d/
/a/b/
```

How do I do this with Linux command line tools? I'm wondering if the following is a good start:

```
grep "\.txt" foo | <what else?>
```

Comment: I think you need `/a/b/c/d/` as output for the second line.

Comment: And `/a/b/` ofor the third.

Comment: You might take look at `dirname` command, for example `dirname /a/b/c.txt` does give `/a/b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming the desired output has a trailing `/` on the 2nd and 3rd lines, otherwise it's inconsistent with the 1st line of output...)

Look at this:

```sh
sed -En '/\.txt$/s!(.*/).*!\1!p' foo
```

where

- `-E` is to use `(` and `)` instead of `\(` and `\)` for grouping
- `-n` tells Sed not to print the pattern space by default
- `/\.txt$/` only matches those lines ending by `.txt`
- `s` run a substitution on those lines we matched with `/\.txt$/`
- `!` is used instead of `/` as a separator, because so we don't have to escape `/`
- `(.*/).*` matches the whole line, but captures only up to and including the last `/`
- `\1` replaces the line with the part that we catpured
- the `p` flag tells Sed to print the line

Comment: Note that `.txt` will also match `§txt`. `.` matches any char if it is not escaped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sh
awk -F/ '$NF ~ /\.txt$/{$NF="";print}' OFS=/ file
```

*Details*:

- `-F/` - set the field separator to a forward slash
- `$NF ~ /\.txt$/` - if the last field text ends with `.txt`...
- `{$NF="";print}` - then zero out the last field text and print the result...
- `OFS=/` - joining the fields with `/`, not the default space.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/KxNjAP):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='/a/b/c/d.txt
/a/b/c/d/e.txt
f
g
h/i
/a/b/c.txt'
awk -F/ '$NF ~ /\.txt$/{$NF="";print}' OFS=/ <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
/a/b/c/
/a/b/c/d/
/a/b/
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this `sed` work?

```
sed 's#\(.*/\).*#\1#;/^[a-z]/d' input_file
```

**Output**

```
$ sed 's#\(.*/\).*#\1#;/^[a-z]/d'
/a/b/c/
/a/b/c/d/
/a/b/
```